# JPA transaction is not starting...how to resolve it?

Tags: jpa

I Am using spring ORM with JPA I am facing issue in while storing the data into data base  can any one help me

Comment: I am not getting any errors and I am  retrieving data also

Comment: should your transactional method

Comment: Yes I am using jpatranscation

Comment: I have a method which returns Jpatranscation

Comment: If I use entityManager.flush() then showing error saying that "no transaction in progress" can any one help me